# How to create array of list in java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I want to create vector array like this in c++ in Java

```
vector<int> tab_u[255]
```

I don't have idea how to fast create. I try this:

```
List<Integer> tab[] = new List[255];
```

but i cant add something

i want something like this

```
tab[0] = {1,2,2,3}
tab[1] = {2,3}
tab[2] = {1}
```

Comment: What does it mean you cannot add something? I am missing what is your problem exactly.

Comment: `tab[0] = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 2, 3);`...

Comment: What happened to your previous identical question? Was it closed?

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer>[] myListArray = new List<>[255];
```

Now you have your `Array` that can contain `Lists` of type `Integer`.
But there is nothing in it.
So to fill it you need to create the lists first, then put them in your array.

```
List<Integer> firstList = new ArrayList<>();  // List itself can't be instantiated, it's abstract
myListArray[0] = firstList;  // there you add the 1st element in your array to be the list you just created
```

Then you can fill your lists

```
myListArray[0].add(1);
```

You can write all this "faster" with some one-liners, but honestly I wouldn't recommend it (unreadable).

FYI:  it is also recommended to define your arrays like this:

```
int[] myIntegerArray;
```

instead the `C`-Way

```
int myIntegerArray[];
```

It's easier to read:  *"int - array - myIntegerArray"*  (the C-Way would read *"int - myIntegerArray - array"*)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can approach this. You create the array and then pre-initialise an ArrayList into every index in the array:

```
   List<Integer>[] tab = new List[255];
   Arrays.parallelSetAll(tab, ArrayList::new);
   tab[0].add(1);
   tab[0].add(2);
   tab[0].add(2);
   tab[0].add(3);
   ....
```

Or, just initialise the list on the array as you allocate it

```
   List<Integer>[] tab = new List[255];
   tab[0] = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 2, 3);
   tab[1] = Arrays.asList(2, 3);
   tab[2] = Arrays.asList(1);
```

Alternatively, you can just work with a two-dimensional integer array;

```
        int[][] tab = new int[255][];
        tab[0] = new int[] {1, 2, 2, 3};
        tab[1] = new int[] {2, 3};
        tab[2] = new int[] {1};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

(...)

ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
l.add(2);
l.add(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initailise array of list.

```
List<Integer>[] list = new ArrayList[255];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedList<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<>()
```

Or

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>()
```

For more information it is recommended to read the documantion -

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can also use map in here like that;

```
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> vector = new HashMap<>();
    vector.put(1, Arrays.asList(1,2,2,3));
    vector.put(2, Arrays.asList(2,3));
    vector.put(3, Arrays.asList(1));
```

Check [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) also.